# Ubuntu suddenly broke audio, apt-get and flash

Tags: apt, sound, google-chrome, flash

I was using my computer normally until I noticed something wasn't right and I rebooted it. Then I couldn't browse webs with flash with chrome, couldn't load an HTML5 video from youtube. When I try to open VLC it says:

```
martin@martin-HP:~$ vlc
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[00000000016dd028] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
```

And sound doesn't work.

When I try to update apt-get:

```
** (appstreamcli:2530): WARNING **: No origin found for file fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

It looks like a hardware problem but the Windows installation works just fine. I suspect it has something to do with the filesystem, but I don't know how to verify it.

Best!

Comment: Try to change the Download Server to `Main Server` from `Software & Updates` and then run `sudo apt-get update` again and after this `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit old, but I got the same error with apt-get on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 LTS.  I found an [old forum post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195585) that seemed to resolve the apt issues for me.  Here are the steps it recommended:

```
sudo -i
apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
mv lists lists.old
mkdir -p lists/partial
apt-get clean
apt-get update
cd
exit
```

Comment: That works. Also I would suggest using `rm` instead of the move. `sudo; cd /var/lib/apt; rm -rf lists; mkdir -p lists/partial; apt-get clean; apt-get update; exit`. As a side note, this clears the cache used by `apt` to avoid having to re-download everything each time you run `apt`. But they will save whatever appears in the output of a "wget", in my case that was an HTTP 302 error!

Answer (score 0):

You verify it by:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdxx
```

It is best to run this in a live cd/usb. Never run it on `/dev/sdxx`. It will destroy your system. If you can't get a live cd/usb, use recovery mode and drop to a root shell (NOT RECOMMENDED).

Comment: Please add that you should never run it from within the system which uses the /dev/sdxx (I did it once and, then got some errors and destroyed my hole system). Only from live cd/usb or from `Advanced Options for Ubuntu`->`recovery mode` at the grub menu.

Comment: Added those things.