# Ubuntu Theme and more

Tags: 16.04, themes, unity-dash

I'm trying to customize Ubuntu 16.04 to reach this aspect:

[image]

Anyone know how customize dash windows and the top bar like the image?
Thanks for help.

Comment: That picture looks like Ubuntu GNOME. https://ubuntugnome.org/

Comment: Icons looks like "numix-circles"

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed [Ubuntu GNOME](https://ubuntugnome.org/).  Most of the styling comes from the GNOME theme and shell extensions.  The easiest way to install the shell-extensions is to go to https://extensions.gnome.org/ in Firefox, enable gnome-shell integration in Firefox, then just enable the extensions from the website directly.

Here's my stab at discovering which shell extensions were used:

- [Applications Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/) for the applications menu
- [Weather](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/613/weather/) for the weather in the top-bar
- [Clipboard Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/) is probably the one that is left-most in the right grouping.

The Do-Not-Disturb-like icon (red circle with a dash through it) is the result of an error in the system (such as apt's [appstreamcli error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789103/ubuntu-suddenly-broke-audio-apt-get-and-flash/843180)).

I have no idea where the chrome icon at the top came from, but you might be able to get something similar with the [Taskbar extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/).

For the theme, @serverus-tux suggested looking at numix-circles.  That looks right, but I didn't look too closely at it.  The install instructions are included at https://itsfoss.com/install-numix-ubuntu/, summarized here:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install numix-gtk-theme numix-icon-theme-circle
```

You can use the gnome-tweak-tool to enable the theme.